# Default class that is extended by all classes in java

Tags: java, class, inheritance, extend

Is there any Default Class that is extended by all the classes by default in Java?

Example: If I have a simple class like:

```java
Class A {
  String a;
}
```

Is this class extending a class by default?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`java.lang.Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class is superclass of all classes.

> Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has Object as a superclass. All objects, including arrays, implement the methods of this class.

You can test it :

```
A a = new A();
if(a instanceof Object){
  System.out.println("Object is superclass of all classes");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In Java, everything (apart from the plain old data types; int, boolean, double etc.) is *implicitly* derived from `java.lang.Object`.

In particular, the class contains useful functions such as `lock()` and `notify()` which are used in thread synchronisation.

For a full list, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is and it is extending `Object` class.

*Object is root class of all java classes.*

Answer (score 2):

"All Classes in the Java Platform are Descendants of Object":
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Answer (score 2):

java.lang.Object is the super clas of all the classes.
all the Java provided classes or the class which you create by your self all are the sub class of Object class by default

Answer (score 1):

yes all the classes by default extend Object class in java. Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is extending `java.lang.Object`.

Answer (score 1):

Class [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has Object as a **superclass**.

Answer (score 0):

yes "Object" class is root class for all other classes. Here is an example to prove it to find the package and class using the Object reference variable.As you can see I have not included Object class explicitly to the project but still I can assign the reference variable to the class "Object" and use it as the class "FindingClass" is inheriting the Object class,Object class reference variable can now access the "FindingClass" object.It is possible only when the current class "FindingClass" is inheriting Object class.

```
package Chapter9.Packages;

   class FindingClass{

    }
    public class FindClass {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        Object obj;
        FindingClass fcls = new FindingClass();
        obj=fcls;
          System.out.println(obj.getClass());
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
class Chapter9.Packages.FindingClass
```

Answer (score -1):

import java.util.*;
default class in java

Comment: Please provide more information. And code could be formatted between backsticks single (`) or triple (```)