# Why Object class is Superclass in java

Tags: java, oop, object, superclass

Why object Class is a super class in java yesterday i had one interview and the interviewer asked me the questions.

Comment: Because Java was designed that way?

Comment: I answred to him that "A object class give the common behavior to every class thats why object class is a super class in java and it provide the common methods to all of them"

Answer (score 4):

Because the Object class, in the java.lang package, sits at the top of the class hierarchy tree.

Comment: I like the use of "hierarchy tree", but this answer needs to be flushed out.

Comment: I answred him that the object class contains some common methods and we can easily override that method in any class so he said finally we used our own logic into the overriding method then what is a need of object class why it is defined?

Answer (score 2):

Because it is just a definition. Actually sec 4.3.2 of `jls8` said:

> The class Object is a superclass (§8.1.4) of all other classes.

There is no more formal way to define `Object` class.

Comment: It's more than just *"a"* single definition .. even if it's summarized as such. The behavior is another part of the puzzle in Java's type system. (For instance, there *could* be a language where an Object type is a direct superclass of every other class, but that's not Java.)

Comment: @user2864740 I agree, but it think that OP want to understand Object class in a formal way.

Comment: I was nit picking the use of "*just* a definition". It's a collection of definitions/rules, this being a true statement, but not the entire story.

Answer (score 2):

Because all objects in Java inherited from `Object` class.

So if you create your class for example `MyObject`, parent for this object will be `Object` class.

It's mean that `Object` is super class for class `MyObject`.

Comment: @user2864740 In your comment you show another example, and we can't use `super` to get `Object` class(in your example), but we always can get `Object` class by casting our object to `Object` class, because all object inherited from `Object` class.

Comment: Yeah, I removed my comment because the use of *inherits* is correct.

Answer (score 1):

All classes in Java by default "extend" the Object class, that's why Object is superclass of every class in Java.

As per the [definition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) of class "Object".

> Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has Object as a superclass. All objects, including arrays, implement the methods of this class.

A similar question which was discussed before ...
[Default class that is extended by all classes in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187218/default-class-that-is-extended-by-all-classes-in-java)

Comment: This is *not* imply that all objects "extend" Object! A class can only have one superclass, thus `class A extends B` shows a case where A does *not* "extend" Object (it extends B) even though A is still a *sub-type* of Object.

Comment: Any class can have Object as it's direct or indirect superclass. If 'A' doesn't extends 'Object' then 'B' does of whose sub class 'A' is. I am just guessing that as per definition since "All objects, including arrays, implement the methods of this class(Object Class)", Object extends Objects.

Comment: The issue is about the wording used. A *inherits* from B (and A *inherits* from Object by extension), but A only *extends* B.