# Why only java.lang. Object is given superclass in java?

Tags: java

Is there any reason sun microsystems make Object for all javaclass for superclass. I face the question my last interview. I hope, I can find answers here 
Thanks

Comment: Do a bit research before asking a question like this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094020/why-object-class-is-superclass-in-java

Comment: I am new this group, next time I will search first, if it not there I will ask question.any thanks for your suggestion @EarlyBird

Answer (score -1):

Following could be the reasons for this design decision,

- By having the Object as the super class of all Java classes, without knowing the type we can pass around objects using the Object declaration.
- Before generics was introduced, imagine the state of heterogeneous Java collections. A collection class like ArrayList allows to store any type of classes. It was made possible only by Object class hierarchy.
- The other reason would be to bring a common blueprint for all classes and have some list of functions same among them. I am referring to methods likehashCode(), clone(), toString() and methods for threading which is defined in Object class.

Please check the below link. I hope it will answer your question.

[Why object is super class in JAVA](http://javapapers.com/java/why-object-is-super-class-in-java/)

Comment: Thanks "sanju Reddy"

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers: link *and* include the relevant details here. If the link dies, this answer is useless.

Comment: @AndyTurner thanks for your valuable suggestion. I am new to this group. Next time I will include the details too.

Comment: Nothing is stopping you doing it now: [edit] your answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13697311)

Comment: Thanks  @YoungHobbit .. I have updated my post